# From cell to DTPicker and back to cell again - VBA - Userform

Tags: excel, vba, date, userform, picker

I am relatively new to all this so please be kind.

I have some DTPickers, these DTPickers are supposed to fetch data from cells and contain that data when the userform is opened. In this case I have the below code to do that when a button to navigate to the mutliform page is clicked.

```
DTPicker1.Value = Sheets("FirstName").Range("B2").Value
DTPicker1.CustomFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
```

Furthermore I would like the date to be changed and for the value to be updated within the userform, so I got myself some code to do that as follows:

```
Sheets("FirstName").Range("B2").Value = DTPicker1.Value
```

This is run during the DTPicker change event. This is all well and good except there needs to be 20 of these DTPickers. And that means an awful lot of coding the exact same thing again and again and again.

Is there any way to create a loop where I can specify a range for all the information to populate into the 1-20 DTPickers as the multiform page is opened and then when any of their information is changed for that to be stored back into those cells, without having to put the code above into every single DTPicker change event.

IF there is anything at all please help me out, and please if you could also specify where to put any code as well because I'm really not great at this. Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like a "control array" might work for you - eg see http://www.siddharthrout.com/index.php/2018/01/15/vba-control-arrays/

Comment: Also  - for loading the dates, you can refer to controls by `Me.Controls("nameHere")` so you could use a loop like (eg) `For i = 1 to 20: Me.Controls("DTPicker" & i).Value = Sheets("FirstName").Cells(i + 1, "B").Value: Next i `

Comment: @TimWilliams That loop looks great however I can't quite figure out how to adapt the control array for my project.

Comment: Based on your other question you seem to have pairs of datepickers and checkboxes?  I can try to give you a basic idea, but I can't write it all for you...

Comment: @TimWilliams Yeah I have a column of checkboxes and a column of DTPickers, I have tried to write a class module and got

`Public Sub DTPickerArr()

Dim Sh As Worksheet
Set Sh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("FirstName")

Dim DTPicker(1 To 18) As Object
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To 18
Sh.Range("B1").Value = DTPicker(i).Value
Next i

End Sub`

But I don't know how to call this module for every single DTPicker change event

Comment: Posted something in your other question